# Get localname from attribute in lxml

Tags: python, lxml, xml-namespaces

**Question:**

I can get `element.tag` name without namespace using `lxml.etree.QName(element).localname`.
How to do similar with `element.attrib` ?

---

**Example:**

Assuming this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root xmlns="some_ns" xmlns:soc="some_other_ns" >
    <someTag attr1="something" soc:attr2="something else"></someTag>
</root>
```

This script returns `attrib` with namespace for the second attribute:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse('test.xml').getroot()
ns = { 'n':'some_ns', 'son':'some_other_ns' }
print ([e.attrib for e in root.xpath('./n:someTag', namespaces = ns)])
```

Output:

```
[{'{some_other_ns}attr2': 'something else', 'attr1': 'something'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QName` for attributes too.

```
tag = root.xpath('./n:someTag', namespaces = ns)[0]
for a, v in tag.attrib.items():
    print(etree.QName(a).localname, v)
```

Output:

```
attr1 something
attr2 something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mzjn's answer, I could write a function that outputs the attributes as dict like `e.attrib` does.

```py
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse('test.xml').getroot()
ns = { 'n':'some_ns', 'son':'some_other_ns' }

def attrib_localnames(a):
    out={}
    for n,v in a.attrib.items():
        out[etree.QName(n).localname]=v
    return out

print ([attrib_localnames(e) for e in root.xpath('./n:someTag', namespaces = ns)])
```

Output:

```py
[{'attr1': 'something', 'attr2': 'something else'}]
```